# How do I use crosstab on this table? I'm not understanding it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a query that switches the month name to be the column headers and the goal column to be the values underneath each.

Table name = asset_management.kba_goals

Data set looks like this:

| month | kba_goal |
| --- | --- |
| January | 34 |
| February | 35 |
| March | 36 |
| April | 37 |
| May | 38 |
| June | 39 |
| July | 40 |
| August | 41 |
| September | 42 |
| October | 43 |
| November | 44 |
| December | 45 |

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation, which in Postgres can use `filter`:

```
select max(kba_goal) filter (where month = 'January') as january,
       max(kba_goal) filter (where month = 'February') as february,
       . . .   -- fill in the rest of the months
       max(kba_goal) filter (where month = 'December') as december
from t;
```